# Copy shape key data path in emission node strength give : NameError: name 'bpy' is not defined

Tags: bones, shape-keys, emission

I am a beginner with Blender and try to learn animation.

I create a robot which have energy state on it arm (when it is full, medium and empty).

[image: energy state]

I want to manage it easly with a bone system, where each light will be link to a specific bone. If i move the first bone on Z axis it need to turn on/off the green light, the second bone turn on/off the yellow light and the third bone turn on/off the red light

[image: bones to manage energy state]

I created some Shape keys for each bone and want to copy their data path in the right emission node to change the strength with my bones.

[image: emission node with the copy data path of shape keys]

It works for my green light, but when i try to do the same for others i got this message in blender info log :

`Error evaluating number, see Info editor for details: Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "<string>", line 1, in <module>`

`NameError: name 'bpy' is not defined`

I don't understand why it work for my first light but not for the others, someone can explain me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When I copy my shape key data path, I have to right click the shape key and select *Copy as New Driver* and then on my strength emission node right click and select *Paste Driver*.

[image: copy as new driver]

[image: paste driver]